# Program not able to find file even though the file is in the same folder (text file)

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: The image is the way the files are stored.] I am making a programming project with school and everything else is working; However, the program cannot find the file even though it is in the same folder.

```
with open("song_artists.txt") as textfile:
    lines = [line.split("\n") for line in textfile]

##for item in lines:

newItem = str(lines[random.randint(0,2)])
#print(newItem)
artist, song, blank = newItem.split(",")
artist = artist[2:len(artist)]
song = song[0:len(song)-1]
print(artist)


for x in range(len(song)):
    if song[x] == " ":
        print(song[x+1])
```

The code above is where the error is happening. The error message is: File "W:\year 11\Computer_Science\Programming\20_Hour_Project\Project Code.py", line 61, in 
    with open("song_artists.txt") as textfile:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'song_artists.txt'

Comment: You are probably running the python file from "home" directory, you need to add the full path to the text file or change terminal folder to 20_Hour_project

Comment: add ```import os;print(os.getcwd())``` to the beginning to see where you are. Use ```open(r"W:\year 11\Computer_Science\Programming\20_Hour_Project\song_artists.txt")````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a working directory problem. You probably are executing it from a different folder. To see where you are running it from use:

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

So to locate `songs_artists.txt` based on `Project Code.py` path use this:

```
import os

THIS_FILE_PATH = os.path.abspath(__file__)
THIS_FILE_FOLDER_PATH = os.path.dirname(THIS_FILE_PATH)
SONG_ARTIST_FILE_PATH = os.path.join(THIS_FILE_FOLDER_PATH, 'song_artists.txt')

with open(SONG_ARTIST_FILE_PATH) as textfile:
    lines = [line.split("\n") for line in textfile]
```

...